# Using JNDI properties file in OpenEJB embedded mode

Tags: jndi, openejb

Eventhough the jndi properties file is kept in the classpath its not loaded and JNDI properties when configured in JVM arguments in ANT its working fine.

```
<jvmarg value="-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory"/>
```

How to configure the JNDI thorugh properties so that even when

**Context=new InititalContext()** is used in the EJB's the JNDI properties that are configured in properties needs to be loaded.

Thanks,

Velmurugan R

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make sure the jndi.properties file is at the root of the classpath and not in a META-INF/ directory or any other location.  By root, I mean some directory that is parallel to a where a META-INF/ would be.  For example:

- foo.jar/jndi.properties
- foo.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

That file is processed by the JVM itself, so if it doesn't work, odds are it is related to it not being on the classpath correctly.